# Desperately but unsuccessfully

Tags: single-word-requests

> He is desperately, but unsuccessfully, trying to prove that he is
>   perfect.

The part “desperately, but unsuccessfully,” does not read well. Is there a word that would combine both?

I am looking for:

> He is _____ trying to prove that he is perfect.

Comment: Yes, *desperately* combines them both.

Comment: Hello, blackened. You seem to be quite proficient at English, if you can identify what 'does not read well'.Have you looked up synonyms of 'desperately' and 'unsuccessfully'? Do any overlap in sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you feel *desperately, but unsuccessfully* doesn't read well. It flows naturally for me.

However, if you need a single word that represents the two things, try [**quixotically**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quixotically):

> [Merriam-Webster, from *quixotic*]
>
> : foolishly impractical especially in the pursuit of ideals
> *especially* : marked by rash lofty romantic ideas or extravagantly chivalrous action

Further:

> If you guessed that *quixotic* has something to do with Don Quixote, you're absolutely right. The hero of the 17th-century Spanish novel *El Ingenioso Hidalgo Don Quijote de la Mancha* (by Miguel de Cervantes) didn't change the world by tilting at windmills, but he did leave a linguistic legacy in English. The adjective *quixotic* is based on his name and has been used to describe unrealistic idealists since at least the early 18th century.

Nobody is perfect, so the desperation of trying to prove oneself to be a representative of that ideal matches the ill-advised fervour of Don Quixote in his *fights against windmills* as he tried to be the paragon of chivalry.

In your sentence:

> He is *quixotically* trying to prove that he is perfect.

Comment: I partly agree with your suggestion. Your example and suggestion is perhaps correct in the specific context, but may not necessarily work in other contexts; especially if the context does contain *unrealistic ideals* part. For example, change the example to: He is desperately, but unsuccessfully, trying to prove that he is brave.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your verb from “is trying” to “is struggling.”

So your sentence would say:
He is struggling to prove that he is perfect.

The verb [struggle](https://www.wordnik.com/words/struggle) has this meaning:

> To have difficulty or make a strenuous effort doing something.

A lot of times a stronger verb is better than adding adverbs.